# Hibernate/Spring HibernateTemplate.findByCriteria(Deatched Criteria dc) executes a sql update on view

Tags: java, hibernate

I am trying to search a view based on given criteria.  This view has a few fields for multiple different entities in my application that a user may want to search for.

When I enter the name of an entity I want to search for, I add a restriction for the name field to the detached criteria before calling `.findByCriteria()`.  This causes `.findByCriteria()` to retrieve a list of results with the name I am looking for.

Also, when I look through my log, I can see hibernate calling a `select` statment.

I have now added another entity to my view, with a few searchable fields.  When I try to search for a field related to this new entity, I get an exception in my log.

When I look through my log with the exception, I can see hibernate calling a `select` statment with an `update` statement right after the `select` (I am not trying to update a record, just retrieve it in a list).

So why is hibernate calling an update when I am calling `.findByCriteria()` for my new entity?

```
    
org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: Could not execute JDBC batch update
    at org.hibernate.exception.SQLStateConverter.convert(SQLStateConverter.java:90)
    at org.hibernate.exception.JDBCExceptionHelper.convert(JDBCExceptionHelper.java:66)
    at org.hibernate.jdbc.AbstractBatcher.executeBatch(AbstractBatcher.java:275)
    at org.hibernate.engine.ActionQueue.executeActions(ActionQueue.java:266)
```

SQL that is executed:

Hibernate:

```
    select
    * 
from
    ( select
        this_.SEARCH_ID as SEARCH1_35_0_,
        this_.ST_NM as ST24_35_0_ 
    from
        SEARCH_RESULT this_ 
    where
        this_.LOAN_TYPE=? ) 
where
    rownum <= ?
```

```
DEBUG 2012-03-21 11:37:19,332 142195  (http-8181-3:org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTemplate):
      [org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateAccessor.flushIfNecessary(HibernateAccessor.java:389)] 
      Eagerly flushing Hibernate session

DEBUG 2012-03-21 11:37:19,384 142247  (http-8181-3:org.hibernate.SQL):
      [org.hibernate.jdbc.util.SQLStatementLogger.logStatement(SQLStatementLogger.java:111)]
```

```
update
    SEARCH_RESULT 
set
    ADDR_LINE1=?,
    ASSGND_REGION=?,
    BASE_DEAL_ID=?,
    ST_NM=? 
where
    SEARCH_ID=?
```

Comment: Can you paste the code for your SearchResult model object?

Comment: I added the immutable annotation to my domain class and that fixed the issue I was having.  Thank for the help Jeff.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is probably an update happening because Hibernate is set up to do an autoflush before executing the queries, so if the persistence context thinks it has dirty data, it will try to update it.  Without seeing the code I can't be sure, but I'd guess that even though search_result is a view, your corresponding Java object is annotated on the getters and the object has matching setters.  Hibernate doesn't make a distinction between tables and views, and if you call a setter, Hibernate will assume that it has data changes to update.

You can tweak how you build your Java objects for views by adding the @Immutable annotation (or hibernate.@Entity(mutable = false) depending on which version you're using.  This should be enough to indicate to Hibernate to not flush changes.  You can also annotate the fields directly and get rid of your setters so that consumers of the SearchResult object know that it's read only.